# Installing Windows in ATA harddisk

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I want to reinstall my PC with Windows 7, but I have a problem with my hard disk, I use ATA harddisk, so I need driver for my hard disk. But I cannot found any driver, I decide to install windows xp, but I wonder about the same problem like before, my question is, is ATA harddisk support for windows XP SP 3 ? XP SP 2 ?

regards,

Answer (score 3):

you mean SATA?
you need a driver for the controller, not for the hard drive (unless the hdd is bigger than 2 TB - xp won't work with that)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are meaning SATA, as in "Serial ATA" rather than PATA, which is more commonly known as IDE.

Generally as Magnetic_dud say you will need to find out what SATA controller you have in your system and create a driver floppy disk in order to set it up when installing Windows.

I have seen some systems that had a SATA controller that you could set up to use "PATA Emulation" (or some similar description) in the BIOS and so use with an older OS like Windows XP without having to install a special set of drivers but that option is very dependant on what controller is actually in your system.

Other than that you may get away with not having to give the driver during installation, as it may "just work" in a degraded mode until you can get into Windows itself to install the driver from your motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: I would say MOST controllers that aren't OEM-specific have some kind of PATA/IDE compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

Actually all Windows XP, Vista, 7 support ATA=IDE harddisks as ATA drivers Windows have preinstalled fully comply to ATA specification. You dont need to install any driver for your ATA harddisk.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question really hard to read. Also, I'm sure it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow as it isn't programming related. Maybe it belongs on Power User or somewhere similar.

That being said, ATA is the classic HDD standard and is supported on Windows XP, all versions, without a problem. You only start needing drivers for your SATA controller if you enable AHCI mode.